# Can not verify a contract on Etherscan (with a library)

Tags: etherscan

I tested my first contract and wanted to verify the contract on etherscan:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0xc73adf8d3ee480e483f45c9c84ee88269407e95d

For some reason I can not verify the code.

I just made a really simple contract. I copied the ERC20 functions and made one fallback and one sucide function. I use the safemath lib. More or less just copied the code and tried some own lines.

In short the code is:

1. lib safe math functions
2. constructor with no arguments
3. erc20 functions
4. fallback function
5. suicide function

that's all.

I combined the code and made a flat file with orcale-combine.solidity. To make sure I don't mess it up with the compiler I copied the flat code into REMIX and deployed it.

But it always tells me:

> Sorry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for 'SpeculativeMania' does NOT
>   match the Contract Creation Code for
>   [0xc73adf8d3ee480e483f45c9c84ee88269407e95d].
>
> Contract name(s) found: 'SPECMN' , 'SafeMath'  Unable to Verify
>   Contract at this point time.

Just for detailed info. This is the contract source code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }
  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }
  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }
  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}
contract SPECMN {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    string public constant name     = "Speculative Mania";
    string public constant symbol   = "SPCMN";
    uint8  public constant decimals = 18;
    uint256 public rate = 10;
    // todo
    uint256 public constant _totalSupply = 1000000;
    uint256 public      _totalSupplyLeft = 1000000;
    uint256 tokens                       = 0;
    // vars
    mapping(address => uint256) balances; 
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowedToSpend;
    address public contract_owner;
    uint256 currentBlock = 0;
    uint256 lastblock    = 0;
    // init function
    function SPECMN(){
        currentBlock = block.number;
        lastblock    = block.number;
    }
    // ## ERC20 standards ##

    // Get the total token supply
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 thetotalSupply){
        return _totalSupply;
    }
    // Get the account balance of another account with address _queryaddress
    function balanceOf(address _queryaddress) constant returns (uint256 balance){
        return balances[_queryaddress];
    }

    // Send _value amount of tokens to address _to
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success){
        require(
            balances[msg.sender] >= _value
            && _value > 0);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to]        = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to,_value);
        return true;
    }
    // Send _value amount of tokens from address _from to address _to
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success){
        require(
            allowedToSpend[_from][msg.sender] >= _value
            && balances[_from] >= _value
            && _value > 0);
        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to]   = balances[_to].add(_value);
        allowedToSpend[_from][msg.sender] = allowedToSpend[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    // Allow _spender to withdraw from your account, multiple times, up to the _value amount.
    // If this function is called again it overwrites the current allowance with _value.
    // this function is required for some DEX functionality
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success){
        allowedToSpend[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }
    // Returns the amount which _spender is still allowed to withdraw from _owner
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining){
        return allowedToSpend[_owner][_spender];
    }
    // Triggered when tokens are transferred.
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    // Triggered whenever approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) is called.
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    // ## ERC20 standards end ##
    // ## Custom functions ###
    function() payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        tokens       = msg.value.mul(rate);
        currentBlock = block.number;
        if(rate > 1 && currentBlock.sub(lastblock) > 3000){
            rate = rate.sub(1);
            RateChange(rate);
            lastblock        = currentBlock;
        } 
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        _totalSupplyLeft     = _totalSupplyLeft.sub(tokens);
        contract_owner.transfer(msg.value);
        MoneyTransfered(contract_owner,msg.value);

    }
    function shutThatShitDown() public {
        require(msg.sender == contract_owner);
        selfdestruct(contract_owner);
    }

    // 
    event RateChange(uint256 _rate);
    // 
    event MoneyTransfered(address indexed _owner, uint256 _msgvalue);

}
```

I'm quite sure I am messing something up with the library

Comment: The way you're adding the library looks OK, aren't you supposed to put the name of the contract you're deploying? Your contract is called `SPECMN`, but it looks like you're telling it you want to deploy a contract called `SpeculativeMania`

Comment: Well, I tried various options like: Speculative Mania, SpeculativeMania, SPCMN. Didn't succeed :/

Comment: Right now I think I somehow need to fill in a corresponding lib address. But where do I get this address?

Comment: Verification works to me for that contract. I successfully verified it Etherscan https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc73adf8d3ee480e483f45c9c84ee88269407e95d#code and in Blockscout as well https://blockscout.com/eth/rinkeby/address/0xc73adf8d3ee480e483f45c9c84ee88269407e95d/contracts